# Conditionally inserting toggleable checkboxes in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I’ve put together a renewal processing list for the insurance agency I work for. Unfortunately I cannot share this sheet so I will do my best to explain the issue I’m having.

The spreadsheet is a large list of policy renewal dates (Client, effective date, line of coverage, etc.). One of the columns is titled “quoting.” Which our agents will check if they're in the process of quoting a line of coverage for one of our clients.

Now, on a separate sheet I have a column of indexed data displaying each client that is in the process of being quoted. Next to this column I want to have several columns, each with checkboxes, allowing everyone to see what appointed carriers were quoting the indexed lines of coverage with.

My problem is obviously that every time somebody checks a client on the renewal list, whatever checkboxes the other clients are associated to in the separate sheet will be off by one (the indexed values will move but the checkboxes will not).

Long winded question, but in this scenario is there any way to have a toggleable row of checkboxes appear and disappear based on the presence of an indexed value?

I would assume that this is maybe something that can be done in google scripts app documentation, but I’m not super familiar with it. I'd love to learn though.

Comment: Yes you can insert and remove check boxes programmatically.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please read [ask], https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior and https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Adding Checkboxes

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast("Entry")
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    e.source.toast("In");
    e.range.offset(0,1,1,3).insertCheckboxes();
  };
}
```

Demo:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Cooper for giving me exactly what I was looking for in terms of auto-populating checkboxes using Scripts. Great first step. 

I am still trying to figure out how I can do this with information that is constantly changing. I have the following formula in column one of my spreadsheet: 

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(SMALL(IF('COMBINED DATA'!J:J = TRUE, ROW('COMBINED DATA'!D:D), ""), ROW('COMBINED DATA'!D:D)), ""))`

Comment: This returns each row number that has a check box which evaluates as 'TRUE'. When these boxes are selected, these row numbers that are returned on the separate sheet will ebb and flow up and down the sheet. I'm trying to figure out how I can get these rows of checkboxes to essentially follow constantly changing numbers listed in that array column. Any advice? I apologize if that doesn't make sense, I'm still trying to make sense of this myself and this would be a really handy tool if it worked the way I'm imagining.